# Edition of St. Vincent of Lerins' "The Commonitory" Approved by the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, tradition, imprimatur, st-vincent-of-lerins

One might think that to find a copy of St. Vincent of Lerins' "The Commonitory" (or Commonitorium) that has received some kind of approbation from the Catholic Church would be an easy task. But it is not.

The best approximation I could come up with (in English) is this: [*New Advent "Commonitory"*](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3506.htm)---which is hardly an original book.

It does, however, provide a source, which beginning on pg. 123, is this: [*Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers*](https://ia801600.us.archive.org/33/items/selectlibraryofn11scha/selectlibraryofn11scha.pdf)

[image]

Finally, the question posted here: [Has the Church stated any advantages or reasoning or prompting to re-formulating positively the Catholic Church's salvation doctrine?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30898/has-the-church-stated-any-advantages-or-reasoning-or-prompting-to-re-formulating)
provided a link to a "Vincentian Canon" at Fordham University; but alas, the link is no longer valid. I would have liked to see what was there; and in particular, what was meant by "Vincentian Canon."

Hence, other than the two above working links, I have not even been able to locate a hard-copy of Lerins' *Commonitorium* with an approbation by competent (Catholic) ecclesiastical approval in *any* language---including Latin---from the stacks of a Catholic college I live near.

QUESTION: Does anyone know of an edition of St. Vincent Lerins' *The Commonitory* (preferably English---but any other language O.K.) which has formally been approved by the Catholic Church with either a valid Imprimatur or Approbation?

Thank you.